# root scope of DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is the example code:

```
// startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
   services.AddScoped<ConcreteA>;
   services.AddScoped<ConcreteB>;
   services.AddScoped<ConcreteBDependency>;

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
   app.UseStatusCodePages();
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
   ConcreteA.Run(app.ApplicationServices);
}
_____________________________________________________

public class ConcreteA
{
   public static Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      ConcreteB _concreteB = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConcreteB>();
      ... 
   }

}

public class ConcreteB
{
   private ConcreteBDependency _dependency ;
   public ConcreteB(ConcreteBDependency denpendency)
   {
      _dependency = denpendency
   }
}
```

I have asked a lot question about scope of services, I thing this question would be the last piece of the puzzle:

Below are my questions:

Q1- is `_concreteB` created under the DI container's root scope?

Q2-since `ConcreteB` has a dependency of `ConcreteBDependency`, an instance of `ConcreteBDependency`(let's say it is called `_dependency` internally) before`_concreteB` was created via the `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConcreteB>();`, so is `_dependency` also created under the DI container's root scope?

Q3- if both of `_concreteB` and `_dependency` are all created under the DI container's root scope, do we need to disable the scope validation check in `program.cs` as

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .UseStartup<Startup>()
 .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
 options.ValidateScopes = false)
 .Build();
```

Comment: `serviceProvider` in `ConcreteA.Run` is the same object as `app.ApplicationServices`, so you're just calling `.GetRequiredService` against the same service provider instance, albeit at a different location. To .NET, there's no difference when it invokes the method.

Comment: @John so are `_concreteB` and `_dependency`  all created under the DI container's root scope,

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about here. What is "root scope"? There's a situation of essentially "no scope", which would be the closest thing to "root", but that's simply objects with singleton lifetimes. All other objects are created in *some* scope.

Comment: In the case of services with a "scoped" lifetime, that generally equates to a request in ASP.NET Core, i.e. they exist between when a request is received and when a response to that request is eventually sent. During that time and in the context of a single request, the instance will be the same no matter how many times it's injected.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1- is _concreteB created under the DI container's root scope?

Yes, `IServiceProvider serviceProvider` is root service provider. But, you could not resolve a scope service directly from root provider. Try to change

```
    public class ConcreteA
    {
        public static void Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ConcreteB _concreteB = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConcreteB>();
        }
    }
```

> Q2-since ConcreteB has a dependency of ConcreteBDependency, an
>   instance of ConcreteBDependency(let's say it is called _dependency
>   internally) before_concreteB was created via the
>   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService();, so is _dependency
>   also created under the DI container's root scope?

For `ConcreteBDependency`, it is resolved by scope from service collection. Again, you could not resolve service from root scope.

> Q3- if both of _concreteB and _dependency are all created under the DI
>   container's root scope, do we need to disable the scope validation
>   check in program.cs as

The default value for `ValidateScopes` is true and you should leave it like that unless you know exactly what you are doing otherwise you risk nasty memory leaks (or object already disposed exceptions) by unreleased services.

You could refer [Scope validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#scope-validation)